# mplayer2 license whitelist on yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded, mplayer, dragonboard

I am using dragonboard 410C + yocto, and I’m trying to build Mplayer2 .
mplayer2 refuses to compile due to it’s commercial license:

> … was skipped: because it has a restricted license not whitelisted in
>   LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST

I have already tried adding to local.conf:

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = “commercial”
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = “commercial_mplayer2”
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = “mplayer2”
```

(did not work)

ant other idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information needed for adding correctly components with different licenses to local.conf:
http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#enabling-commercially-licensed-recipes

The problem is that you are overwriting the WHITELIST with new values each time, so it only takes the las value.
You can either delete the last two lines or add a "+" before "=" in the last two lines. This way:

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = “commercial”
```

or

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = “commercial”
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += “commercial_mplayer2”
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += “mplayer2”
```